# label in kivy doesn't update in while loop

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to make a timer that updates a label to see the current amount of time remaining. I have a button that when you press should start the 2 min timer. For some reason the label doesn't update. Is there something wrong with the way I am doing this?

Here is my code:

```
import time

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label


Builder.load_string("""
#:import sla kivy.adapters.simplelistadapter
#:import label kivy.uix.label
<ListItemButton>:
    selected_color: 0, 0, 1, 1
    deselected_color: 0, 0, 0, 1

<MenuScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        #cols: 2
        #rows: 2
        size: 800,480
        Label:
            id: output
            text: "0 min 0 s"
            font_size: 60
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 400, 100
            pos: 200,425
        Button:
            id: statheader
            text: "2 min"
            font_size: 40
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 600,100
            pos: 150,800
            background_color: 0,0,1,1
            on_press: root.startTimer(int(2))

""")

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    tww = 0
    def startTimer(self, what):
        self.tww = what*60
        while self.tww > 0:
            minute = self.tww/60
            print(minute)
            second = self.tww - minute*60
            print(second)
            self.ids.output.text = str(minute) + " min " + str(second) + " s"
            self.tww -= 1
            time.sleep(1)

sm = ScreenManager()
menu_screen = MenuScreen(name='menu')
sm.add_widget(menu_screen)

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Is there something else that `self.ids.output.text` should be?

Answer (score 1):

Kivy's graphics can't update until your while loop finishes - during the loop, only the content of the loop is run (repeatedly), and Kivy's normal functions are blocked.

You should instead use `Clock.schedule_interval` to run computations every frame without blocking other functions, or run your while loop in a thread.

Comment: Bummer. Thanks for the answer